# Eclipse not finding Main_Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

For some reason when I design this Android app, the .java file is not finding the main_activity and will not run the app.
Where it says: R.activity.main_activity there is a red line under "Main_Activity".
Does anyone know why, how can I fix this?
Thanks!

```
package com.test.helloworld;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num);

    }
```

Comment: You have R.activity.main_activity in your question and R.layout.activity_main in your code. Which are you using ?

Comment: Also, remove android.R import; from the import list.

Comment: Sorry I dind't realize that I'm using R.layout.activity_main @2Dee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you imported **android.R;**, the resource-id file for the android SDK.
you will probably want to import your own R.java that was generated for you.

Comment: Which R.java file do I use?

Comment: None. Remove it and clean you project. Then tell us if you have any errors. Project > Clean in Eclipse.

Comment: That seemed to work thanks a lot, so I don't need to import any R.java files? @RED_

Comment: No, R.java references things in the res folder, activity_main being on of them, it builds automatically based on what is in the res folders. What you imported was android.R. This is for some of android default references such as their defaults icons and text. It was trying to look for activity_main in there when it is not there. Please mark an answer as correct if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Import as

```
import android.com.test.helloworld.R;
```

instead of

```
import android.R;
```

Also clean your project and also run it again.

Comment: do I replace the com.test.helloworld with my package name?

Comment: u should just import your R.java file as i mentioned. Yet error occurs clean ur project and run again. Your R.java will be generated with your package name